# AWK/SED to remove first part of path

Tags: sed, awk

I'm writing a script to pull a users AD Home and I've been able to get the users `SMBHome` from `dscl` command and I need the path like this:

```
//SERVER-01/HOME-EMPLOYEE/User_Name
```

to look like this:

```
/HOME-EMPLOYEE/User_Name
```

I've tried used the `awk` command of `/usr/bin/awk 'BEGIN{RS="//"; FS="/"}{print$1}'` but I think I'm going in the wrong direction here. Would `sed` be a better choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example, using sed:

```
kent$  echo "//SERVER-01/HOME-EMPLOYEE/User_Name"|sed 's#//[^/]*##' 
/HOME-EMPLOYEE/User_Name
```

Answer (score 3):

Using either `sed` or `awk` is overkill:

```
SMBHOME=//SERVER-01/HOME-Employee/User_Name
NOSERVER=/${SMBHOME#//*/}
```

Comment: Can you explain what program you are using to do this? I've never seen any regular expression done this way.

Comment: Program?.. not a program, it's good ole bourne-again shell [(bash)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) programming :)

Comment: @russeller: This is `bash` or `ksh` notation. The `#` (hash) means 'remove the head of the string which matches (non-greedily)'. You can use `##` which does that greedily. You can use `%` (percent, with a 't' at its tail) to remove material from the tail of a value, and `%%` to do that greedily. There are other options in `bash` and probably some other options in `ksh`. It was not supported in Bourne shell. It should be supported by `/bin/sh` as POSIX mandates it (see [parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)).

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "//SERVER-01/HOME-EMPLOYEE/User_Name" | cut -d'/' -f4,5,6
```